# How to create contours correctly with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour, contourf

I have data ([link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwwhEMUIYGyTYV9HclR2NzZESHc/view?usp=sharing)) of the form given below:

```
Y   X 0 X 10    X 20
15  4.83    4.91    4.99
20  4.58    4.65    4.73
25  4.43    4.49    4.56
```

I am trying to plot contours of the X **label values**, in these cases 0, 10, 20 (as z in code) with x-axis as X values and y-axis as Y values. Plots are created using the code:

```
import numpy as np
import re
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

with open('contour.dat', "r") as data:
    while True:
        line = data.readline()
        if not line.startswith('#'):
            break
    data_header = [i for i in line.strip().split('\t') if i]
_data_ = np.genfromtxt('contour.dat', skiprows = 2, delimiter = '\t')
x = _data_[:, 0]
y = _data_[:, 1:]


y_n = []
for i in range(len(data_header)):
    if data_header[i][0] == 'X':
        y_n = np.int_(np.append(y_n, i))
y_index = [data_header[i] for i in y_n]
z = []
for i in range(0, len(data_header)):
    z = np.append(z, re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", data_header[i]))
z = z.reshape(len(z), 1)
z = np.tile(z, (len(x), len(x)))


with PdfPages('./on_tau.pdf') as p_tau:
    _p_vs_tau_ = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
    _p_vs_tau_.clf()
    p_vs_tau = plt.subplot(111)
    x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    surf = plt.contourf(y, x, z, 30, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.gist_heat,
                           linewidth=0, antialiased=False, alpha = 1.0)
    surf1 = plt.contour(y, x, z, 30, colors = '#000000',
                           linewidths=0.5, antialiased=False, alpha = 1.0)
    plt.clabel(surf1, inline=1, fontsize=6)
    p_tau.savefig(bbox_inches='tight')
    plt.close()
```

But I am not getting the correct contours. I believe I am doing something wrong somewhere, probably while repeating z values. How to get the contours correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this generate the contour you are looking for?  Modified code from your z=np.tile statement (now commented out):

```
#z = np.tile(z, (len(x), len(x)))
xm = np.tile(x,11)
xm = np.reshape(xm,(11,10)).T
zm = np.tile(z,10).T

with PdfPages('./on_tau.pdf') as p_tau:
    _p_vs_tau_ = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
    _p_vs_tau_.clf()
    p_vs_tau = plt.subplot(111)
    #x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    surf = plt.contourf(y, xm, zm, 30, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.gist_heat,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False, alpha = 1.0)
    surf1 = plt.contour(y, xm, zm, 30, colors = '#000000',
                       linewidths=0.5, antialiased=False, alpha = 1.0)
    plt.clabel(surf1, inline=1, fontsize=6)
    p_tau.savefig(bbox_inches='tight')
    plt.close()
```

Comment: Do you know how to get the contour of the last value also?

Comment: I think it has to do with your data being exactly on the boundary.  After the zm assignment statement add: zm = zm.astype(float); zm[zm==100.] += 0.001.  Then it should show the last contour line.